# Helm Charts - can you dynamically generate n StatefulSets?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an application that requires a configurable number of master nodes and replicas. Is there any way to dynamically generate a n stateful sets where n is the number of master nodes I have? The number of master nodes is currently set in values.yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `until` function.

**values.yaml**:

```
masterCount: 5
```

**templates/statefulset.yaml**:

```
{{ range $k, $v := until ( .Values.masterCount | int) }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-{{ $v }}
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx-{{ $v }}"
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-{{ $v }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-{{ $v }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
{{ end }}
```